# Android adding Double numbers

Tags: java, android

I would like to add talkPrice, textPrice and dataPrice and have the total be displayed in a field on the page but I am at a loss. Any help would be great.
Pretty much based on what is selected it changes the Double `<name>Price` to match I just need it to add up
Here is what I have so far

```
package com.bestbuymobile;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class att_ind extends Activity{
String debug = "ATT_IND";
Double talkPrice = 0.00;
Double textPrice = 0.00;
Double dataPrice = 0.00;
Double totalPrice = 0.00; 

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.att_ind_layout);
        Log.d(debug,"Calling Talk_Plans Function");
        Talk_Plans();
        Log.d(debug,"Calling Text_Plans Function");
        Text_Plans();
        Log.d(debug,"Calling Data_Plans Function");
        Data_Plans();
}
public void Talk_Plans() {
    Log.d(debug,"");
    Spinner talk = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.att_ind_talk_spinner);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.att_ind_talk_plans, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    talk.setAdapter(adapter);
    talk.setOnItemSelectedListener(new Talk());
}
public void Text_Plans() {
    Log.d(debug,"");
    Spinner text = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.att_ind_text_spinner);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.att_ind_text_plans, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    text.setAdapter(adapter);
    text.setOnItemSelectedListener(new Text());
}
public void Data_Plans() {
    Log.d(debug,"");
    Spinner data = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.att_ind_data_spinner);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.att_ind_data_plans, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    data.setAdapter(adapter);
    data.setOnItemSelectedListener(new Data());
}

class Talk implements OnItemSelectedListener {
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {

        Log.d(debug,"Listening for Talk packages");
        if(parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString().equals("None")) {
            Log.d(debug,"No talk package selected");
            textPrice = 0.00;
        }
        if(parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString().equals("450 Minutes")) {
            Log.d(debug,"450 Minute package selected");
            textPrice = 39.99;
        }
        if(parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString().equals("900 Minutes")) {
            Log.d(debug,"900 Minute package selected");
            textPrice = 59.99;
        }
        if(parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString().equals("Unlimited Minutes")) {
            Log.d(debug,"Unlimited Minute package selected");
            textPrice = 69.99;
        }
    }
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }
}
class Text implements OnItemSelectedListener {
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
        Log.d(debug,"Listening for Text packages");
        if(parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString().equals("None")) {
            Log.d(debug,"No messaging package selected");
            textPrice = 0.00;
        }
        if(parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString().equals("Unlimited")) {
            Log.d(debug,"Unlimited Messaging package selected");
            textPrice = 20.00;
        }
    }
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }
}
class Data implements OnItemSelectedListener {
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
        Log.d(debug,"Listening for Data packages");
        if(parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString().equals("None")) {
            Log.d(debug,"No data package selected");
            dataPrice = 0.00;
        }
        if(parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString().equals("300 MB")) {
            Log.d(debug,"300MB data package selected");
            dataPrice = 20.00;
        }
        if(parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString().equals("3 GB")) {
            Log.d(debug,"3GB data package selected");
            dataPrice = 30.00;
        }
        if(parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString().equals("5 GB")) {
            Log.d(debug,"5GB data package selected");
            dataPrice = 50.00;
        }
    }
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }
}
}
```

Comment: *_Do not_* use doubles for financial things.  Please.  By Odin's beard.

Comment: what do you suggest I use? double primitive?

Comment: Use [`BigDecimal`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html).  Please.

Comment: can you give me an example of adding BigDecimals? Thanks

Comment: Um, a quick Google search would find that for you, but `bigDec1.add(bigDec2)` would do just fine.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjava%5D+bigdecimal+financial has over 1000 posts on SO about BigDecimal and financial situations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need make a TextView to display it, and get a reference to your TextView.

Then you can do something like this:

```
textView.setText(String.valueOf(var1 + var2 + var3 + etc...));
```